# Kids traveling with a different passport in their parents' country without being previously registered in a consulate

Tags: visas

Can a kid enter with a different passport with which normal citizens  would need a visa for the parents' country if the kid travels with their parents and they have the related passport but the kid hasn't for not being registered?

To make this easier to understand, I'll give an example:

A kid was born in the US from Pakistani parents and the kid has never been registered in a Pakistani consulate nor do they have a Pakistani passport. The kid has only a US passport. 
Generally US citizens need a visa for Pakistan.
In this case, if the kid has only the US passport but they travel with their Pakistani parents, can the kid enter hassle-free without a visa??

Comment: I don't think there's a general rule that applies to all countries, so the first part of this question is too broad to be answered here.  If you're specifically interested in Pakistan, I would recommend editing your question to remove the first paragraph.  If you're specifically interested in another country, then edit your question to include that information instead.

Comment: No Pakistan was just an example. Anyways I thought that since almost every country applies the principle of filiation/jus sanguinis, the kids who have the passport of any country other than their parents' one would enter visa-free even if the holders of the same passport the kid holds need a visa to enter the destination country.

Comment: Usually there are some formalities for a child born outside a country to claim citizenship from a parent, requiring review of evidence of the relationship. What those formalities are depends on the country, but generally the end result will be the child being able to obtain a passport that will be the evidence of citizenship they will use to enter the country.

Comment: I was not assessing dual citizenship scenarios, but rather I was assessing cases in which the parents had little time to obtain  passport for their child.

Comment: Although the case in the question does involve dual citizenship, I agree that is not relevant. The key is whether a given country would admit a child as a citizen based simply on an adult citizen saying "This is my child", without prior formalities and documentation of the child's citizenship. The question is not answerable in general, but for the countries I know about the child would not be admitted.

Comment: Every country has some means to obtain travel documents on an urgent basis via the nearest embassy/consulate/high commission.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I suspect that the US would admit a child in such circumstances, but it would have to be at the land border, and it might take quite a while for the immigration officer to evaluate the claim of US nationality for the child.  I would never count on this working.

Comment: @phoog In the example I'm meaning Pakistan as the destination, not the US.

Comment: I think @phoog is just presenting the US as a example of a country that does admit someone who is actually a citizen without a passport. However, it is definitely not hassle-free, and would be especially risky if the child was born abroad and has neither a US passport nor a Consular Report of Birth Abroad.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan indeed, I was responding to your statement "for the countries I know about" in the belief that one of those countries is the US, and also in the context of the general question in the question's first paragraph rather than of the specific example that follows.

Comment: @phoog an American father did manage to make his Australian-born new born baby enter the US without any VWP or any visa, he just testifies for him. However and obviously, his Australian wife did not enter likewise.

Comment: @user at which port of entry? Is there a publicly available source for this anecdote?

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant airports. I read an answer here on SE some time ago.

Comment: In my country of origin citizenship is automatic by filiation even if a person has been never registered in a consulate in their own life while born abroad.

Comment: I have just voted to close this question as requiring more details. The first paragraph is impossibly broad, and, according to a comment, Pakistan is not the actual target country.

Comment: In some places, you would have to prove the child is actually yours in order to be allowed to leave.  I took my kids from USA to Canada with no problem, but it took several hours to talk our way back in!

Answer (score 10):

There are three different issues here:

- What is the citizenship of the child?
- Can the child prove the citizenship to the satisfaction of the border officials?
- Can the child prove the citizenship to the satisfaction of the airline staff?

The child in the example may well **be** a Pakistani citizen, with no easy way to prove it. Many countries fine *airlines* if they bring passengers without the necessary entry documents, so airlines do a check and they are usually not prepared to compare birth certificates or whatever -- they want to see a passport or national identity card.

Comment: I assumed the child traveling with their own parents and make as a guarantee for their child to enter, since every country in the world applies filiation

Comment: @user, not every country accepts citizenship by descent in *every* case, and the airline staff will not want to make that call.

Comment: @user the airline is not going to make judgment calls about any country's nationality law, and they are not going to make a judgment call about the validity of the birth certificate or other evidence of parent-child relationship.  The laws I've seen, in any event, do not make airlines responsible to judge passengers' admissibility, but only to make a good faith effort to check that they have certain documents.  That's why they require passports and visas.   A recently naturalized US citizen can show up with a naturalization certificate bearing a photograph, but the airline won't care.

Comment: @user Where is the proof that the adults *are* the parents of the child? (Of course if the child had valid documents in their own right, such proof would be irrelevant).

Comment: Birth certificate in the scenario I'm presenting.

Answer (score 4):

The child will be considered as a US citizen and is required to take Pakistani visa.

Comment: Assuming the child is under age 21, Pakistan does allow dual citizenship. There may be an option of getting Pakistani citizenship by descent and a Pakistan passport.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes, but the OP is asking what happens if they try to fly to Pakistan without a Pakistani passport.